# Convert xlsx and xlsm to csv in perl

Tags: perl, csv, xls

Hi I am trying convert an *xlsx* and *xlsm* file to `csvs` using `perl`.
I have been using `xls2csv` but this doesnt work .
`cannot read ampster1.xlsm` is the error I get .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xls2csv is part of the old Spreadsheet::ParseExcel distribution, which handles only .xls files but not the newer formats. Try the [Spreadsheet::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX) module.